# How to show different content dependent on accessing device (user-agent)?

Tags: amp-html

For one URL I wish to show different content which depends on whether the accessing device is using iOS or Android (because I want to show technical instructions suitable for the specific device). Is that somehow possible given that custom JavaScript is disallowed on AMP pages? Is there maybe some special CSS selector or something else I could use?

Comment: Start here - Detecting Android vs iOS in AMP: https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/components/amp-script/

Comment: @JayGray Thank you, looks good! I will give it a try later.